# How to return rows of query result in PostgreSQL's function?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I've tried following tutorials for many times but failed.
Could someone give me some examples please?
Here is my code, it prompts that "ERROR:invalid type name 'SETOF RECORD'"

```
create or replace function find() returns SETOF RECORD
as $$
declare A SETOF RECORD;
begin
    A=(
        select x,y
        from .......

    )
    CASE WHEN EXISTS A 
    THEN returns query A
    ELSE returns query (
        select x,y
        from ......
    )
    END;

end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: What is the error you get? What exactly are you trying to do? (**[edit]** your question, do not post additional information in comments)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ways to declare set returning function that I remember at the moment:

```
--example 1
create or replace function test() returns SETOF RECORD
as $$
begin
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,100);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
--test output
select * from test() AS a(b integer)

--example 2
create or replace function test2() returns TABLE (b integer)
as $$
begin
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,100);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
--test output
select * from test2()

--example 3
create or replace function test3() returns SETOF RECORD
as $$
declare
  r record;
begin
    FOR r IN SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,100) LOOP
      RETURN NEXT r;
    END LOOP;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
--test output
select * from test3() AS a(b integer);

--example 4
create or replace function test4() returns setof record
as $$
    SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,100)
$$ language sql;
--test output
select * from test4() AS a(b integer);

--example 5
create or replace function test5() returns setof integer
as $$
begin
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,100);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
--test output
select * from test5()

--example 6
create or replace function test6(OUT b integer, OUT c integer) RETURNS SETOF record
as $$
begin
    RETURN QUERY SELECT b.b, b.b+3 AS c FROM generate_series(1,100) AS b(b);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
--test output
select * from test6()
```

Comment: Thanks. And what should I do when I need to decide if the query result exists? What I want to do is that when it exists then return it, otherwise return result of another query.

Comment: Possibly `FULL JOIN`, `UNION` or `DISTINCT ON` would work, depending on query. I think that it doesn't have anything to do with function declaration. You __can't__ store `SETOF RECORD` in variable.